# dynamic expanding row ng2-smart-table Angular

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

i'm trying to expand rows when clicking on a button ,
I found this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-row-components-for-smart-table-cw7q9y
but when enabling actions (comment: actions:false in settings): `//actions:false,` this makes crud operations possible, if I try to add a new row, the expanded row loses control and position.

To understand more the problem proceed like this:

1. comment: actions:false
2. click on any button
3. click the action Add New
4. confirm by clicking on create

You can notice that the red row loses its row position in the table

Comment: Please include relevant codes to the question itself.. Moreover the link is not opening.

Comment: I think that the link works correctly, I tried to add some explanations. I hope it can help.